# Grep for a number in line

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I need to get the below two outputs?

### Input

```
/usr/IBM/WebSphere/7.0/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/bin/java -Declipse.security -Dwas.status.socket=48101
/home/axg009/usr/IBM/WebSphere/8.5/AppServer/java_1.7_64/jre/bin/java -Declipse.security -Dwas.status.socket=48101
```

### Output 1

```
7.0
8.5
```

### Output 2

```
7.0/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/bin/java
8.5/AppServer/java_1.7_64/jre/bin/java
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you actually care whether `grep` is the tool to solve this, or would solutions with other tools also be acceptable?

Comment: You might explain why you want that output, where the input comes from, how the output relates to the input, and what you're going to do with the output.  If you do, then you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 4):

For the first one:

```
grep -oP 'IBM/WebSphere/\K[0-9]\.[0-9]' file
```

For the second one:

```
grep -oP 'IBM/WebSphere/\K[0-9]\.[0-9].*java ' file
```

- `-P` activates Perl regular expressions
- `-o` prints only the matching part
- `IBM/WebSphere/\K` the beginning of the part until `\K` which empties the matching variable, so this wil not be part of what is printed
- `[0-9]\.[0-9]` a digit followed by a dot followed by another digit.

  - `.*java` in the second one, you want to match also until the end of the java command (until `java` followed by a space).

Answer (score 3):

```
ps -Aocomm= | sed -ne'/java$/s|.*/\([0-9]\.\)|\1|p'
```

It looks like `ps` output there, but, if so, it is probably a mistake to include the arguments to the commands for which you search. This is especially true if you're `grep`ping the results because the search pattern for *`.*java.*`* or what-have-you will then likely match for the `grep` command you run.

Fortunately you can search only for the `comm=`and name and prune those results as I do above, which should handle *Output 2*. For the first:

```
ps -Aocomm= | sed -ne'/java$/s|.*/\([0-9]\..\).*|\1|p'
```

If it isn't `ps`, then this also works:

```
sed 's|.*/\([0-9]\.[^ ]*\).*|\1|' <in
```

...for *Output 2*, and...

```
sed 's|.*/\([0-9]\..\).*|\1|' <in
```

...for *Output 1*...

Comment: Wow.  Reading that just put me into a deep hypnotic trance . . .

Comment: @RobertL - good. it worked. youre now under my control.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven’t *described* what you want,
but only shown input and output<sup>1</sup>,
there are very many possible answers.

#### Stupid Ones

1. `printf "7.0\n8.5\n"`
2. `printf "7.0/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/bin/java\n8.5/AppServer/java_1.7_64/jre/bin/java\n"`

These have the advantage that you don’t even need to read the input.

#### My Best Guess at What You Really Want

1. This gets to be a little tricky,
   since

   ```
   grep -o "[0-9].[0-9]" input
   ```

   yields the output

   ```
   7.0
   8.5
   1.7
   ```

   because it finds every `digit.digit` sequence,
   and there are two of them on the second line of the input. 
   But

   ```
   grep -o "/[0-9].[0-9]/" input
   ```

   yields the output

   ```
   /7.0/
   /8.5/
   ```

   (every `/digit.digit/` sequence),
   which may be close to what you want, and then

   ```
   grep -o "/[0-9]\.[0-9]/" input | grep -o "[0-9]\.[0-9]"
   ```

   yields the output

   ```
   7.0
   8.5
   ```
2. ```
   grep -o "[0-9]\.[0-9][^ ]*" input
   ```

   gets every sequence of non-blank characters
   beginning with `digit.digit`. 
   `1.7` doesn’t get a line to itself
   because it is included in the `8.5/…` line.

____________
<sup>1</sup> Please, always include example input and output
in your questions. 
But ***also*** describe how you want to get from the input to the output,
or you will get stupid answers.

Comment: In retrospect, I think this answer actually explains why I tranced out while reading @mikeserv's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

**First one:**

```
$ grep -Po '/\K[[:digit:].]+(?=/)' file.txt 
7.0
8.5
```

**Second one:**

```
$ grep -Po '/\K[[:digit:].]+/[^ ]+' file.txt 
7.0/UpdateInstaller/java/jre/bin/java
8.5/AppServer/java_1.7_64/jre/bin/java
```

- For first case, `/\K[[:digit:].]+(?=/)` will get the numbers in the format `/x.y/` where x and y both are digits
- `/\K[[:digit:].]+/[^ ]+` will look for the substring stating from `/x.y/` to a space which is our desired portion in the second case

Comment: I see you’ve embraced my philosophy that any answer that produces the specified outputs is worthy of submission, but at least I did mine ironically.  Your `[[:digit:].]+` regex matches, not just numbers in the form `x.y`, where `x` and `y` are digits, but any non-null string of digits and periods — including integers of arbitrary length (e.g., `7`, `42`, `512`, `65536`, etc.), and also things like `3.14159`, `99.44`, `102.5`, `.0.`, `4.3.32.103443`, `.`, `..`, `.....`, etc.  Of course, that *might* be what the OP wants.

Comment: @G-Man Every solution should be focused on the very question i think..so we can take any example given by OP literally unless OP included level of precision..

Comment: I think the point is that any answer should describe what it does / explain how it works, so readers (the OP and others) can determine what question each answer answers.  By saying that your regex matches `/x.y/`, where `x` and `y` are digits, your answer deceives by omission.